# What does Rhs refer to in a compiler error message about PartialEq?

Tags: iterator, rust

I am trying to create a function that takes two iterators as as parameters and iterates over the items by reference. Each `Iterator` item should implement `PartialEq`.

My first attempt was:

```
fn compute<T: Iterator>(first: T, second: T, len: usize) -> usize
where
    T::Item: std::cmp::PartialEq,
{
    // ...
}
```

This compiles but iterates (as far as I understand) not by reference but by value and the compiler complains about a move when iterating.

My second attempt was something like:

```
fn compute<'a, T>(first: T, second: T, len: usize) -> usize
where
    T: Iterator<Item = &'a std::cmp::PartialEq>,
{
    //...
}
```

resulting in a compiler error:

```
error[E0393]: the type parameter `Rhs` must be explicitly specified
 --> src/main.rs:3:28
  |
3 |     T: Iterator<Item = &'a std::cmp::PartialEq>,
  |                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ missing reference to `Rhs`
  |
  = note: because of the default `Self` reference, type parameters must be specified on object types
```

What does the `Rhs` (Right hand side?) the compiler refers to here mean? Why do I need a reference to it? How do I pass a bounded reference-based `Iterator` into a function?

Comment: Not every iterator has items that it can return references to. I think you need to show how you were trying to use the first `compute` and the compiler error; it's not clear why that wouldn't work.

Comment: When you write `PartialEq` after the `Item=`, it is in a *type context* so it is interpreted as a trait object, not as a trait.

Comment: You are right about the abbreviation: LHS is used for Left Hand Side and RHS for Right Hand Side when talking about binary operators (I personally prefer to refer to them as Left and Right when both are in scope, because I do not like identifiers differing by a single letter).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`PartialEq` is a trait that allows you to compare two values. Those two values do *not* have to be of the same type! The *generic type* `Rhs` is used to specify what type we are comparing with. By default, the value of `Rhs` is the same as the type that is being compared to:

```
pub trait PartialEq<Rhs = Self> 
where
    Rhs: ?Sized,
```

In this case, you are actually requesting that the iterator value be the  *trait object* `&PartialEq`. As the error message states:

> because of the default `Self` reference, type parameters must be specified on object types

We could specify it:

```
fn compute<'a, T>(first: T, second: T, len: usize) -> usize
where
    T: Iterator<Item = &'a std::cmp::PartialEq<i32>>,
```

or

```
fn compute<'a, T: 'a>(first: T, second: T, len: usize) -> usize
where
    T: Iterator<Item = &'a std::cmp::PartialEq<&'a T>>,
```

---

> but iterates (as far as I understand) not by reference but by value

It's quite possible for it to iterate by reference. Remember that `T` is *any* type and that `i32`, `&i32`, and `&mut i32` are *all* types. Your first example is the formulation of the signature I would use:

```
fn compute<T: Iterator>(first: T, second: T, len: usize) -> usize
where
    T::Item: std::cmp::PartialEq,
{
    42
}

fn main() {
    let a = [1, 2, 3];
    let b = [4, 5, 6];

    compute(a.iter(), b.iter(), 1);
    compute(a.iter(), b.iter(), 2);
    compute(a.iter(), b.iter(), 3);
}
```